# Firebase | JS | Add particuar particuar information to a user account

Tags: javascript, firebase, account

Actualy Firebase get `profile.providerId`, `profile.uid`, `profile.displayName`, `profile.email` and `profile.photoURL`.
How to add particuar information to a user account saved by firebase like `profile.birthday`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use something like [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/)